# When does $x^3+y^3=kz^2$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

For which integers $k$ does
$$
x^3+y^3=kz^2
$$
have a solution with $z\ne0$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1$? Is there a technique for counting the number of solutions for a given $k$?

Comment: Do You have a formula describing these decisions? And how it looks?

Comment: The formulas. As in the Pythagorean triples.

Comment: For any $k$ it is always possible to write the solution. Only interest is how to derive a formula for mutually simple solutions.

Comment: @individ: If you have a procedure that lets you do that for any $k$, please write it up as an answer!

Comment: If you allow negative solutions, then for $k=173$ we have $\{x,y\}=\{7741,-7222\},~z=22449$ and $\{x,y\}=\{9757,-5086\},~z=67887$.

Comment: @Lucian: Yes, negatives are fine, but I'm really only looking for _methods_ of solving the equation or proving it has no solution (for a given $k$). I'm not interested in particular instances. For example, can it be proved that the equation is solvable for all $k$, or alternatively can someone exhibit a $k$ such that no solution exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer (Version III)**

It turns out if we allow $x$, $y$ to be negative, all $k$ is possible!
For any integer $t$, define

$$
\begin{cases}
x_o(t) &= 1-3t^2\\
y_o(t) &= 3t^2 + 6t + 2\\
z_o(t) &= 3(3t^2+3t+1)\\
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
x_e(t) &= 12t^2 + 12t - 1\\
y_e(t) &= -12t^2 + 12t + 1\\
z_e(t) &= 6(12t^2+1)
\end{cases}
$$
We have
$$
x_o(t)^3 + y_o(t)^3 = (2t+1) z_o(t)^2
\quad\text{ and }\quad
x_e(t)^3 + y_e(t)^3 = 2t z_e(t)
$$

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{cases}
(2t+3)x_o(t) + (2t-1)y_o(t) &= 1\\
(t-1)x_e(t) + (t+1)y_e(t) &= 2
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
\gcd(x_o(t),y_o(t)) = 1\\
\gcd(x_e(t),y_e(t)) = 1 \text{ or } 2\\
\end{cases}
$$

Since $x_e(t), y_e(t)$ are odd numbers, the possibilities that
$\gcd(x_e(t),y_e(t)) = 2$ has been ruled out.
As a result, all the $( x_o, y_o )$ and $(x_e, y_e)$ are co-prime solutions for corresponding
Pell-Fermat equation.

**Answer (Version I)**

(*obsoleted by findings in Version II, keep here for historical reference*)

This is just another set of random data points. The main result is

> If the Diophantine equation $b^2 - 3k a^2 = -2$ has a non-trivial solution $(a,b)$ for positive integer $k$, then 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x &= 6c^2 + 6c + 1\\
> y &= 3c^2 + 6c + 2\\
> z &= 3ab (3c^2 + 3c + 1)
> \end{cases}
> \quad\text{ with }\quad c = k a^2-1
> $$
>   will be a solution for the Pell-Fermat equation $k z^2 = x^3 + y^3$.

Since
$$(2c+3)(6c^2 + 6c + 1)  - (4c+2)(3c^2 + 6c + 2) = -1$$

The pair of $x,y$ generated in this manner is always co-prime.

By brute force searching, the Diophantine equation $b^2 - 3ka^2 = -2$ does have
non-trivial solutions for following list of $k \le 100$.

$$1,2,6,9,17,18,22,34,38,41,54,57,66,81,82,86,89,97$$

As a result, the corresponding Pell-Fermat equation does have a solution for these $k$.
Following is a table showing one solution for each $k$.

$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
z^2 &\times& k &=& x^3 &+& y^3\\
\hline
3^2 &\times& 1 &=& 1^3 &+& 2^3\\
42^2 &\times& 2 &=& 13^3 &+& 11^3\\
1092^2 &\times& 6 &=& 181^3 &+& 107^3\\
3255^2 &\times& 9 &=& 433^3 &+& 242^3\\
17157^2 &\times& 17 &=& 1633^3 &+& 866^3\\
15492906^2 &\times& 18 &=& 156493^3 &+& 78731^3\\
33288^2 &\times& 22 &=& 2773^3 &+& 1451^3\\
101010^2 &\times& 34 &=& 6733^3 &+& 3467^3\\
100761696^2 &\times& 38 &=& 699733^3 &+& 350891^3\\
162393^2 &\times& 41 &=& 9841^3 &+& 5042^3\\
591636585540^2 &\times& 54 &=& 256119733^3 &+& 128079467^3\\
373503^2 &\times& 57 &=& 19153^3 &+& 9746^3\\
540582^2 &\times& 66 &=& 25741^3 &+& 13067^3\\
22216951933755^2 &\times& 81 &=& 3287747233^3 &+& 1643943842^3\\
44651886469302^2 &\times& 82 &=& 5257492813^3 &+& 2628835211^3\\
1052688^2 &\times& 86 &=& 43861^3 &+& 22187^3\\
847778841^2 &\times& 89 &=& 3844801^3 &+& 1924802^3\\
1424787^2 &\times& 97 &=& 55873^3 &+& 28226^3\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Great! Unfortunately this doesn't cover all the $k$, but it's a step in the right direction I think.

Comment: @Charles Actually, this result is a byproduct of a more general approach which study the equations
over the [Eisenstein integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/3}]$. For each $k$, there are finitely many ways to factorize it over $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/3}]$ and for each factorization, the problem can be reduced to the problem of finding a solution for a Diophantine equation on 3 variables. It is pretty complicated, what you see here is my attempt to fix some of the parameters and look at a special case which I can analysis.

Comment: You have left me completely mesmerized, countless times, by your uncanny ability of solving impossible integrals. And now, I find out that there's this completely new side to you. You just never cease to amaze me ! :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian I'm just lucky to have a good reference book next to my bed. I learned the underlying approach from Henri Cohen's book "Number Theory - Volume II: Analytic and Modern methods". Cohen's book has a complete solution to this question for $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ in its section 14.3. Basically, all the primitive solutions for $k = 1$ falls into three disjoint families of parametrization and the primitive solutions for $k = 2$ falls into four disjoint families of parametrization. I just "monkey see, monkey do".

Answer (score 2):

$\qquad\qquad$ **Too long for a comment:** Positive coprime integers *x* and *y* less than $6,000$ :

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ $k=1$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ $k=2$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ $k=3$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ $k=4$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ $k=5$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

Answer (score 1):

If $k=z$, there are no solution by Fermat's Last Theorem.

When $k=1$ a solution can be $x=1$, $y=2$, $z = 3$, because $1^{3} + 2^{3} = 3^{2}$

Another $k=38$ have a solution can be $x =3$, $y=5$, $z=2$ and there are lots of $k$ can be 
solution of that equation, but now I don't know any technique for count how many or what $k$  give a solution.

EDIT:

I found the following solution, I think it isn't the best but:

\begin{equation}
x^{3}  + y^{3} = (x+y)[(x-y)^{2}+xy]
\end{equation}

we can think that $(x+y) = z^{2}$ and $k =[(x-y)^{2}+xy]$.

now using $xy = \frac{1}{4}[(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^{2}]$

we can found $3$ solutions,

$1) k =[(x-y)^{2}+xy] \iff x+y$ is a square;

$2) k =[\frac{3}{2}(x-y)^{2}+\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}] \iff \frac{x+y}{2}$ is a square;

$3) k =[3(x-y)^{2}+(x+y)^2] \iff \frac{x+y}{4}$ is a square;

Comment: I can generate as many instances as I like by choosing coprime $x$ and $y$ and finding the square divisors of $x^3+y^3.$ But that doesn't help me solve particular cases with known $k$.

Comment: ok ok, now I think a way to solve the problem given $k$ but some diophantine equations are really hard

Comment: I edit with a simple way to solve

Comment: I still don't understand. How could I use this to determine if there is a solution with $k=173,$ say?

Comment: Bro,  if $x+y=z^2$ let $x=z^2+a$ and $y=-a$ for any $a$. Then substitute and u have urself a formula

Answer (score 0):

Well you can and draw another formula.  $$x^3+y^3=kz^2$$  $$x=k(b^2-a^2)(b^2+2ba-2a^2)c^2$$  $$y=k(b^2-a^2)(2b^2-2ab-a^2)c^2$$  $$z=3k(b^2-a^2)^2(a^2-ab+b^2)c^3$$

The most interesting thing there is that the formula that led, like should not give mutually simple solutions, but after sokrasheniya on common divisor can be obtained and are relatively prime solutions. This means that the formula itself describes as relatively prime so no. Coprime solutions - there are private solutions.

the equation:    $$(X+1)^3-X^3=Y^2$$

Solutions can be written if we use the solutions of Pell's equation:  $p^2-3s^2=1$

Then the solution can be written:  $$X=\pm2ps-p^2$$  $$Y=p^2\mp3ps+3s^2$$

If we make the change:  $$q=2ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$  $$t=4ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$

Then the solutions are of the form:  $$Y=t^2-tq+q^2$$  $$X=t(t-2q)$$

If we make the change:  $$t=3ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$  $$q=4ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$

Then the solutions are of the form:  $$X=-4t(t+q)$$  $$Y=4t^2+6tq+3q^2$$

There are formulas, but I have to rewrite no time.  You can see it there.

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/98941

Comment: Your $x$ and $y$ aren't coprime, so I can't use them. I don't know what the rest of your post has to do with my problem -- the parameter $k$ doesn't even appear.

Comment: @Charles as you do not receive?  Can a formula for You not understand?  I tried to write as simply as possible.

Comment: Individ, I don't even see how what you wrote relates to my problem after the x, y, z assignment, and that part obviously doesn't help me since x and y are not coprime. Where does X come from, and why are you computing $(X+1)^3-X^3$? I mean, sure, I can solve that equation, but what does it have to do with mine?

Comment: I'll ask you the same question I asked kimiko88: how would you use this to solve the case $k=173$, for example? That is, either find coprime $x$ and $y$ such that $x^3+y^3=173z^2,$ or else prove that no such values exist.

Comment: @Charles here he wrote some particular solution. The link you gave there is another solution.  You were not looking?

Comment: @Charles  Using the first formula can be found for example that decision. $7741^3-7222^3=173*22449^2$ Here on the forum do not like the formula. So I don't want to continue the discussion.

Comment: The link doesn't appear to contain any text. I'm not interested in particular solutions, I'm interested in methods for finding a solution given $k$, or prove that none exist.

Comment: Mutually simple solution is a special case. $18397^3+7034^3=173*194943^2$ I'm too lazy to teach You arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

A question to achille hui

"Actually, this result is a byproduct of a more general approach which study the equations over the Eisenstein integers Z[e 2πi/3 ] . For each k , there are finitely many ways to factorize it over Z[e 2πi/3 ]  and for each factorization, the problem can be reduced to the problem of finding a solution for a Diophantine equation on 3 variables."

Achille, do you have any references about this approach? Any published papers? Do you mean QUADRATIC Diophantine equation of 3 variables? Thank you, Vlad

Comment: Yes, I mean quadratic Diophantine equation. I learned the approach from a book by Henri Cohen. Look at my comment to Lucian in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation: $$(a+b)^3+(a-b)^3=2a(a^2+3b^2)$$ Now let $a^2+3b^2=c^2$. We want to find a general equation for this. Note that $$(m-n)^2+2mn=(m+n)^2$$ Therefore, substitute $m\mapsto m^2$ and $n\mapsto n^2k$ then $$(m^2-k\cdot n^2)^2+k(2mn)^2=(m^2+k\cdot n^2)^2$$ Let $k=3$, and it follows that $a=m^2-3n^2$ and $b=2mn$, given that $a^2+b^2=(m^2+3n^2)^2$. $$\therefore (m^2-3n^2+2mn)^3+(m^2-3n^2-2mn)^3=2(m^2-3n^2)(m^2+3n^2)^2$$ We could also substitute  $m\to 3m^2$ and $n\mapsto n^2$ to get $$(3m^2-n^2+2mn)^3+(3m^2-n^2-2mn)^3=2(3m^2-n^2)(3m^2+n^2)^2$$